# AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged ASP.NET CORE & Angular 2+

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core

I am having a weird issue, from one moment to another my backend which is developed in asp.net core 3.0 suddenly stopped. I can see in the command prompt (cmd) the following error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
  Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/post/getPosts/7/1
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
  CORS policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
  Authorization failed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
  AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
  Request finished in 1.2346000000000001ms 401
```

However I have no idea why this happened, I tried to update all dependencies but I had no results, I have spent hours on this issue.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like `/api/post/getPosts/7/1` endpoint is being called and authentication is failing. Maybe the token that the caller has has expired?

Comment: I have removed all the cache info from the browser but the issue is still there. Log out and log in but there are no good results at all.